# How to use count(‘condition') over(partition by xx) in SQL

Tags: sql

Here is the database:

[image]

The first table is named `Trip` and the second table is `Users`.

`CLIENT_ID` and `DRIVER_ID` are foreign keys for `USERS_ID` in the `Users` table. I want to find how many orders cancelled by the non-banned driver and non-banned passenger for each day (`Trip.Status != 'completed' and Users.Banned ='No'`).

My code is :

```
SELECT
    t.Request_at AS 'Day',
    COUNT(Status != 'completed') OVER (PARTITION BY t.Request_at) AS 'Cancellation Num' 
FROM
    Trips t
JOIN 
    Users u1 ON t.Client_Id = u1.Users_Id AND u1.Banned = 'No'
JOIN 
    Users u2 ON t.Driver_Id = u2.Users_Id AND u2.Banned = 'No' 
WHERE
    t.Request_at >= '2013-10-01' AND t.Request_at <= '2013-10-03'
GROUP BY
    t.Request_at
```

The results for '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-03' are right(both equal to 1). But it turns wrong at '2013-10-02'. It becomes to 1, but it should be 0. I do not know where is the mistake in my code. Could someone help me?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you really want conditional aggregation, not a window function:

```
SELECT t.Request_at AS Day,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status <> 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_cancellations
FROM Trips t JOIN 
     Users u1
     ON t.Client_Id = u1.Users_Id AND
        u1.Banned = 'No' JOIN 
     Users u2
     ON t.Driver_Id = u2.Users_Id AND u2.Banned = 'No' 
WHERE t.Request_at >= '2013-10-01' AND t.Request_at <= '2013-10-03'
GROUP BY t.Request_at;
```

Note:  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column aliases.

Comment: It works! Thanks for your help. By the way, could you tell me why the window function does not work here?

Comment: @YihaoMao . . .Well, actually, it should generate a syntax error because `Status` is not defined after the `group by`.  I don't know why your code even runs.

Comment: It does not need to be defined, because 'Status' is one attribute in the first table(the fifth column).

Comment: @YihaoMao . . . The window function is executed "after" the `group by`.  There is no `status` after the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    t.Request_at AS 'Day',
    COUNT(case when Status != 'completed' then 1 else null end) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Request_at) AS 'Cancellation Num' 
FROM
    Trips t
JOIN 
    Users u1 ON t.Client_Id = u1.Users_Id AND u1.Banned = 'No'
JOIN 
    Users u2 ON t.Driver_Id = u2.Users_Id AND u2.Banned = 'No' 
WHERE
    t.Request_at >= '2013-10-01' AND t.Request_at <= '2013-10-03'
GROUP BY
    t.Request_at
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `SUM` function instead?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But all counts change to 0. It's really strange. If my condition in COUNT() is wrong, other days' results should be wrong too. But it only gets wrong at '2013-10-02'.